# What is the influence of humidity on NDIR $\rm CO_2$ measurements?

Tags: atmospheric-science, spectroscopy, absorption, infrared-radiation

### The Question

I would like to use an NDIR $\rm CO_2$ sensor to measure $\rm CO_2$ in the 0.1-3% range. However, in the course of my experiments, humidity may vary from ambient (50-60%) up to nearly 100% (non-condensing though). Thus, I am wondering:

**Does non-condensing humidity influence NDIR CO$_\mathbf{2}$ measurements, and if so in what ways?**

Indeed, while condensation is a well-known issue in NDIR sensing since micro-droplets of water can deposit onto the reflective parts of the sensor—thus perturbing light-paths and affecting the measurements—I could not find much information about the influence of non-condensing humidity[1, 2].

---

### In the Literature

##### Kim *et al.* (2017)

Kim *et al.*[2] present the influence of humidity and temperature on CO$_2$ measurements using a custom NDIR sensor. Their results (personal drawing of Table 3's data) are presented below. There seems to be a sharp decrease of the influence of humidity on the measured CO$_2$ values. However, as the authors did not indicate the standard errors of their measurements, the presented deviations may just arise from low precision of their sensor at low CO$_2$ concentrations. What strikes me is that they present **humidity-induced error of about 5 up to 20%** depending on the humidity / temperature levels.

[image]

##### Makhdoumi Akram *et al.* (2020)

Makhdoumi Akram *et al.*[1] present measurements of the influence of humidity on their sensor (figure below). However, their error bars are of the same magnitude as the variations that they present, so it is not evident to tell whether humidity really has an influence on the variation that they observed or not. They furthermore state that "According to
the results, it can be seen that sensor performance was almost
stable under different humidity situation.", which would indicate **no influence of humidity on their measurement whatsoever**.

[image: Influence of the humidity on CO2 measurements]

---

### Confusion

I am thus rather confused about what to think on that matter, and I do not have the hardware at hand to test this quickly. Any help on this topic would thus be welcome.

---

### References

[1] *Low cost and miniaturized NDIR system for CO$_\mathit{2}$ detection applications*, Makhdoumi Akram *et al.* (2020), DOI: [10.1108/SR-06-2019-0140](https://doi.org/10.1108/SR-06-2019-0140)

[2] *Effects of Temperature and Humidity on NDIR CO$_\mathit{2}$ Gas Sensor*, Kim *et al.* (2017), DOI: [10.5369/JSST.2017.26.3.179](http://dx.doi.org/10.5369/JSST.2017.26.3.179)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** theoretical considerations show that humidity should have virtually no influence on NDIR pCO$_2$ measurements, as long as there is no condensation on the reflective optical parts of the sensor.

---

### Basics of the NDIR Sensing Scheme for CO$_2$

Thankfully, the [HITRAN](https://hitran.org/) (HIgh-resolution TRAnsmission molecular absorption) database is available freely, allowing anyone to grab the absorbance spectra of various molecules. Additionally, HITRAN even provides a Python API ([HAPI](https://hitran.org/hapi/)) allowing one to quickly get the desired absorbance spectra instead of [having to deal with raw spectral lines](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/157859/conversion-from-spectral-line-intensity-to-absorbance-hitran). Here is the absorbance spectra of CO$_2$ and water vapour using a Lorentzian broadening profile and dilution in air at 1 atm and 323 K (50°C) (Source: HITRAN / HAPI). Choosing a relatively high temperature (50°C) was done on purpose as [it yields much higher H$_2$O vapour pressures than at 0 or 20°C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water).

[image: CO2 and water vapour absorption in the 3-5μm range]

As you may notice, there is over 6 orders of magnitude between the absorption of CO$_2$ at 4.26 μm, and that of water vapour at 4.0 μm. These wavelength were chosen since they are ordinarily used for ratiometric NDIR CO$_2$ measurements[1].

Now let us write the NDIR ratiometric measurement principle, supposing that $CO_2$ and water vapour are the only two absorbing species at the considered wavelength $\lambda_1 = 4.00$ μm and $\lambda_2 = 4.26$ μm. We will be following a similar train of thought as Hodgkinson *et al.*[1], and a sensing scheme depicted below (also from [1]).

[image: NDIR ratiometric measurement principle]

At each wavelength, we will measure the intensity:

\begin{equation}
I_{\lambda_i} = I_{0,\lambda_i} \cdot e^{-A_{\lambda_i}} \approx I_{0,\lambda_i} \cdot (1-A_{\lambda_i})
\end{equation}

wherein $A_{\lambda_i}$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
A_{\lambda_i} = \eta_{CO_2} \cdot A_{CO_2,\lambda_i} + \eta_{H_2O} \cdot A_{H_2O,\lambda_i}
\end{equation}

With $\eta_X = \frac{p_X}{p_0}$ the fraction of $X$ in the gaseous mixture ($p_0$ the total pressure) and $A_{X, \lambda_i}$ the absorbance of substance $X$ at wavelength $\lambda_i$ if it were alone in the mixture (*i.e.* if $p_X = p_0$). In the end, we are interested in the signal $S$ defined as

\begin{equation}
S = 1 - \frac{I_{0,\lambda_1}}{I_{0,\lambda_2}} \cdot \frac{I_{\lambda_2}}{I_{\lambda_1}}
\end{equation}

Let us also assume for the sake of simplicity that $\frac{I_{0,\lambda_1}}{I_{0,\lambda_2}}=1$, *i.e.* that our source / detector / filter combinations have the same yields at both wavelengths. This hypothesis yields $S = 1 - \frac{1- A_{\lambda_2}}{1- A_{\lambda_1}}$. Finally, putting it all together

\begin{equation}
S = 1 - \frac{ 1- (\eta_{CO_2} \cdot A_{CO_2,\lambda_2} + \eta_{H_2O} \cdot A_{H_2O,\lambda_2}) }{1- (\eta_{CO_2} \cdot A_{CO_2,\lambda_1} + \eta_{H_2O} \cdot A_{H_2O,\lambda_1}) }
\end{equation}

### So What is the Influence of Water Vapour?

In order to determine the influence of water vapour on CO$_2$ measurements using the above-described scheme, we will now compute $S$ with and without water vapour—*i.e.* 0 and 100% Relative Humidity (RH)—for different CO$_2$ concentrations and compute the relative difference between the two values. This should in turn yield a good approximation of what would happen to the CO$_2$ reading of the sensor, give or take the non linearity of the $S\leftrightarrow pCO_2$ function (see [1], Figure 6).

To do so, let us derive the value of the $\mathcal{A}_{X,i} = \eta_{X} \cdot A_{X,\lambda_i}$ products. We can also make the hypothesis that each channel (at 4.00 μm and 4.26 μm) is 100 nm wide, with a flat profile (this latter hypothesis allows one to "smooth" the absorbance coefficients of H$_2$O and CO$_2$, which are otherwise abruptly varying from one wavelength to the other, and corresponds to the reality of NDIR sensing, which often involves measurement channels several hundreds of nanometres wide). This leads the following $A_{X,\lambda_i}$ values, choosing a path-length of 1 cm for the sake of simplicity:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
A_{CO_2,\lambda_1} = 3.62\cdot 10^{1} \qquad A_{H_2O,\lambda_1} = 9.74\cdot 10^{-6}\\
A_{CO_2,\lambda_2} = 3.98\cdot 10^{-7} \qquad A_{H_2O,\lambda_2} = 6.62\cdot 10^{-7}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Regarding the fraction of H$_2$O at 100%RH, we can take [0.1218 at 50°C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water). Comparing the $S$ values obtained at 0%RH and 100%RH yields the following plot,

[image: S with and without HR]

onto which the two curves are barely distinguishable for CO$_2$ concentrations above 10 ppm. Plotting the relative error on $S$ as a function of CO$_2$ concentration results in:

[image: Error as a function of pCO2]

### Conclusion

The water-vapour-induced error on NDIR CO$_2$ sensing is thus theoretically extremely low, and quickly decreases with the measured pCO$_2$, falling below 1% for pCO$_2$ above 5-10 ppm. This comforts me in my first interpretation of the results of Kim and Makhdoumi Akram. **However** it should be noted that all the afore discussion holds **only as long as there is no condensation on the reflective optical parts of the sensor**.

---

**Note:** this whole discussion is assuming that the emitting-receiving parts of your sensor are not sensitive to humidity for other reasons—*e.g.* corrosion of the reflective surfaces, if any, an issue that may be mitigating by using gold-coating.

---

### Further Discussion

*What follows is a (not so) brief summary of private correspondence with Jane Hodgkinson, reader in applied photonics at the Cranfield University, who kindly took the time to proofread this Q&A, and gave me additional valuable insights on the matter.*

H$_2$O cross-sensitivity of NDIR gas sensing works as follows: water vapour has absorption in lots of regions but especially in a band centred around 2.8 μm (see first figure, above) and again across the 5-7 μm region. At the edges, these bands can cross-respond a little bit to both the 4.0 μm reference channel and the 4.3 μm measurement channel.

Although this is normally negligeable — as demonstrated above — the degree of cross-response towards water vapour depends critically on the filter characteristics on each channel. Indeed, in the example above we considered rather narrow (100 nm-wide) measurement and reference channels, and H$_2$O cross-response was thus not significant for CO$_2$ measurements. This generally holds true for CO$_2$ sensing as the CO$_2$ and water vapour absorbtion bands are quite distant from each other. Hence, even with measurement channels several hundreds of nanometer wide, this should not be an issue.

However water vapour cross-response can be much more significant for measurements of CH$_4$ made using the same principle[2]. That is a function of the quality of the filters used; if they are very broad or have poor out-of-band blocking characteristics, the above-mentioned edges of water vapour absorption bands may partially overlap the filter band-pass window. Most filters supplied within integrated photoreceivers for NDIR are from high quality suppliers, though, such as [Infratec](https://www.infratec.eu/sensor-division/ir-filters/), for instance.

That being said, even if you **do** see a cross-response, it is often predictable (and therefore can be removed by measuring the H$_2$O by some other means) – this is the approach used in [2]. It can also be modeled by taking a good set of high-resolution spectral data (Hitran or PNNL), accurate transmission curves for the filters, if relevant a known output spectrum for the IR source (especially if it has marked spectral features) and knowing the pathlength. Then, you would have to model both the measurement and reference channels, and combine them to give the apparent signal. Where the cross-response becomes problematic, however, is when the prediction does not match up to reality, for example if some temperature changes can’t be taken into account (*e.g.* thermal expansion of filters leading to drift in their spectra).

A further effect that might be seen is the following. Water vapour can simply displace other atmospheric gases. So you can measure the CO$_2$ concentration and it will be accurate, but could be lower than the concentration would be if you were to strip out the water, which might be an issue in certain applications. For example airway capnography is performed on breath that starts out saturated with water vapour, but that water vapour is then generally filtered out by anaesthetic filters (this is known in medical devices to measure exhaled CO$_2$). Even without active filtration, condensation within the sampling lines can have a partial stripping out effect, and although you sensor accurately measures the CO$_2$ concentration of the gas mixture inside its chamber, the latter might not be representative of that inside the lungs. Yet, this latter phenomenon should be limited to 2-5% depending the room temperature, given the changes in [water vapour pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water) with temperature. That being said, some applications—for example in environmental science—require use of the “dry fraction” of different gases in atmospheric air.

---

### References

[1] *A low cost, optically efficient carbon dioxide sensor based on nondispersive infra-red (NDIR) measurement at 4.2μm*, Hodgkinson *et al.* (2012), DOI: [10.1117/12.922258](http://dx.doi.org/10.1117/12.922258)

[2] *Compact Non-Dispersive Infrared Multi-Gas Sensing Platform for Large Scale Deployment with Sub-ppm Resolution*, Wastine *et al.* (2022), DOI: [10.3390/atmos13111789](https://doi.org/10.3390/atmos13111789)